# Visualizacion world map con pygal - No data

Tags: python, map, pygal

Estoy con el libro *Python Crash Course* y no consigo visualizar el mapa de World population. Al abrir el archivo .svg en Chrome recibo el error de 'No Data'.

No recibo ningún error cuando ejecuto el programa. Imprimiendo el diccionario `cc_populations` se imprime correctamente, por lo que realmente la información está almacenada.

Gracias por adelantado!

El código es el siguiente:

```
import json
import pygal
from country_codes import get_country_code
from pygal.maps.world import World

wm = World()


filename = 'population_data.json'

with open(filename) as f:
    pop_data = json.load(f)

# Print each country's population

cc_populations = {}

for pop_dict in pop_data:
    if pop_dict['Year'] == '2010':
        country_name = pop_dict['Country Name']
        population = int(float((pop_dict['Value'])))
        code = get_country_code(country_name)
        if code:
            cc_populations[code] = population

# Create map
wm.title = 'World population in 2010 per country'
wm.add = ('2010', cc_populations)
wm.render_to_file('world_population.svg')

print(cc_populations)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya he descubierto el fallo.

No estaba añadiendo los datos correctamente:

```
wm.add = ('2010', cc_populations)
```

debería ser

```
wm.add('2010', cc_populations)
```